# Read/Edit MYSQL xampp database from drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, xampp

I want to read and edit MySQL database from my website which I have built in Drupal. Any suggestion?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Yes, please read this [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has it's API for accessing database. You can start by reading this:

https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database

Comment: Very much appreciated but can anyone elaborate this with example. That would be really appreciated.